# Azure API Management OAuth 2.0 Resource Owner Password Flow

Tags: api, azure, oauth-2.0

i am using the Api Manager service and i have configured my API to use Oauth authentication but to an authentication server in my company, that is, i am not using Azure Active Directory but i get the following error: **An HTTP connection to authorization server could not be established or it has been unexpectedly closed**. And i do not know what it is lack to configure. I tried giving access to the IP of my API in the authentication server but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem. It was due first to my authentication server requiring a certificate so I had to add the certificate "Certificate CA". Then within the configuration of Oauth I had to add as parameters of the bopy the Client Id and secret ID and leave as an authentication method in the body